# Why maven is adding dependent library even if the scope is provided?

Tags: maven

I have added a library with a scope provided but still it is adding some of the child dependencies.
Here is the `mvn dependency:tree`

```
[INFO] +- org.apache.phoenix:phoenix-core:jar:4.10.0-HBase-1.1:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tephra:tephra-api:jar:0.9.0-incubating:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tephra:tephra-core:jar:0.9.0-incubating:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.2.4:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.inject:guice:jar:3.0:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  +- javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.inject.extensions:guice-assistedinject:jar:3.0:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.thrift:libthrift:jar:0.9.0:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- it.unimi.dsi:fastutil:jar:6.5.6:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.twill:twill-common:jar:0.6.0-incubating:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.twill:twill-core:jar:0.6.0-incubating:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.twill:twill-api:jar:0.6.0-incubating:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.ow2.asm:asm-all:jar:5.0.2:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.twill:twill-discovery-api:jar:0.6.0-incubating:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.twill:twill-discovery-core:jar:0.6.0-incubating:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.twill:twill-zookeeper:jar:0.6.0-incubating:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tephra:tephra-hbase-compat-1.1:jar:0.9.0-incubating:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.antlr:antlr-runtime:jar:3.5.2:provided
[INFO] |  +- jline:jline:jar:2.11:provided
[INFO] |  +- sqlline:sqlline:jar:1.2.0:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:13.0.1:provided
[INFO] |  +- joda-time:joda-time:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.github.stephenc.findbugs:findbugs-annotations:jar:1.3.9-1:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.github.stephenc.jcip:jcip-annotations:jar:1.0-1:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.2:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.2:provided
[INFO] |  +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:jar:2.5.0:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.0.1:compile
```

If you look at the last line it is compile

`[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.0.1:`**compile**

Comment: try running again with `-Dverbose` and you will probably see that another dependency (compile scoped) is also pulling in httpclient.

Comment: Could you provide the pom.xml file?

Answer (score 0):

I am able to trace the issue. Comamnd I used to trace.

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes=org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient
```